# Variance of random variable summation

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm having trouble with solving this question:
if we know:
$Y \sim Pois(4.0)$, 
$X \sim Pois(5.0)$, and both $X$ and $Y$ are independent,

what is $Var(X+Y)$?

I first i thought to find the formula for the joint probability and then go from there, but i couldnt find any way to progress further and im not even sure what i did is correct. Any tips on how to approach solving this type of question would be appreciated.

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: yes- we are supposed to assume that, sorry i forgot to mention

Comment: Tip: Never forget to mention that: it is usually very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if $X$  and $Y$ are two independent variables, $Var(X+Y) = Var (X) + Var (Y) $.

If you don't already know this identity, it would be a good idea to prove it algebraically

Comment: Hint: To do so, begin by using the definition of variance, $~\mathsf {Var}[X+Y] ~=~ \mathsf E[(X+Y)^2]-\mathsf E[X+Y]^2~$ then expand things out, making use of the Linearity of Expectation, and an implication of independence .